What counts as an Easy / Beginner Question?
Recently, I posted a question that closed because it was considered a beginner's question. Here is a link to the question:
It is not clear to me what counts as a beginner's question. The question came from an undergraduate (but not first year) text book on Finance. I am hoping somebody can provide me with guidance as what counts as a beginner's question. Personally, I see nothing wrong with allowing a beginner's question but I understand why they are not allowed.

If you can imagine every question that anyone might ask about quantitative finance I do not believe there is an obvious, definitive boundary which defines an "easy" question that is likely to be unsuitable, to a "harder" question that warrants inclusion.
By nature this site is democratic which incurs some subjectivity. In your case, personally I would have left it open, but I can see that it really fits in the category "basic arithmetic requirement after understanding of definition of model". The basic arithmetic is assumed common knowledge on the site, and one does not expect questions such as "how to do basic division" or "how to calculate percentage increase". An understanding of the model is relevant. This is fair question in my opinion, although some models are so easily researchable, and potentially so widely understood, that their inclusion may not be warranted either.
